# Does javascript have a way I can cycle through objects without a for loop?

Tags: javascript

I have come up with this and it seems to work:

```
  var errors = [];
     for (var key in response.data.modelState) {
         for (var i = 0; i < response.data.modelState[key].length; i++) {
             errors.push(response.data.modelState[key][i]);
         }
     }
```

However is there in modern browsers a way that I can do without setting a loop with var i = 0?  I was hoping for something like foreach but that does not work.

Comment: you trying to loop within another loop

Comment: What is wrong with the classic for loop? Is there a real reason behind the question or just curiousness?

Comment: It would be useful to thee the input and expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two loops in that code.

- You can replace the outer loop with `Object.keys` and `forEach`
- You can replace the inner loop with a single call to `errors.push`

Like so:

```
var errors = [];
Object.keys(response.data.modelState).forEach(function(key) {
    errors.push.apply(errors, response.data.modelState[key]);
});
```

That loops through the "own" enumerable property names on `response.data.modelState`, and then pushes all of the values for each entry onto `errors` (using a trick that lets you push all the entries from an array into another array: `.push.apply(target, source)`).

In ES6 you'd be able to use the spread operator for the second part:

```
let errors = [];
Object.keys(response.data.modelState).forEach(key => {
    errors.push(...response.data.modelState[key]);
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this really good answer.  I will accept in a few mins.  By the way you mention ES6.  Are there any estimates as to when we'll start seeing that in browsers?  Thanks

Comment: @Anne: Chrome, Firefox, and IE Edge are actively adding support. But I'd think for the next couple of years, we'll need to be transpiling for anything meant to be used outside a controlled environment. I use [Babel](http://babeljs.io) for that.

Comment: It won't be all of ES6 in a particular version, each iteration of browsers will support some of ES6 features, for example, the rest parameters are already implemented in FF and Edge: http://caniuse.com/#search=rest%20parameters

Comment: @laruiss: Indeed, I should have highlighted that. Another useful reference: http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/ But just for clarity, above I'm not using rest args, I'm using the spread operator: http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#spread_(...)_operator

Answer (score 3):

ES5's `.forEach()` is what you are looking for:

```
var errors = [];
for (var key in response.data.modelState) {
    response.data.modelState[key].forEach(function (modelStateValue) {
        errors.push(modelStateValue);
    });
}
```

forEach is implemented in IE9+ http://caniuse.com/#search=forEach

`response.data.modelState[key]` has to be an object of type `Array`

Answer (score 0):

Jquery has a [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) function.

Javascript also offers [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) for arrays, and this is supported by vast majority of modern browsers today (IE8 and lower do not support it). There is also the [for-in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop, but this should be avoided as it is meant to enumerate object properties, not iterate.

It's worth mentioning that .forEach() is [significantly slower](http://jsperf.com/fast-array-foreach) than looping over an array using a regular for loop.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach